# my jquery image slider isn't smooth in chrome but is fine in firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

So I have this really simple image slider this this page here
http://charlesbergertattoos.com/tattoos which works just fine in IE and firefox. The animation is really smooth and the images actually slide, but in chrome it's not smooth at all.

Comment: It looks like there is different behaviour on Chrome, first it tries to fade out the image then slides it. In Firefox it just slides.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - **demo:** http://jsbin.com/oruxip

because on click event your calling `slider_animate()` directly your not calling your plugin

in chrome when you do that the `slide_widths` var is 0 because you defined and executed the assignment logic outside of the event function so its static

you have 2 options put that line inside the function `slider_animate`

```
var slide_widths = $(e).find('.holder > li:first').width();  
//correct the variables name accordingly
```

or call the plugin function itself which is `imgSlider`

Answer (score 0):

Well in the caraousel.js on line no. 32

try using something synonymous to the following code instead of the one present
I mean the  .animate() call... should be something like animate({marginLeft: "233px"})

```
$('.browse.button.next.right').parent().find('.holder').children('li').eq('0').animate({marginRight: "-233px"});
```

this will work as previous click

```
$('.browse.button.next.right').parent().find('.holder').children('li').eq('0').animate({marginLeft: "233px"})
```

this will work as next click

and these syntax work in both chrome and firefox..

Comment: here 233px is the width of the image...so we have to slide -/+ 233 px the image div..for left/right traverse